# Trying to make my image's position change randomly

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ibaction

I am using Xcode to try to change my images position randomly every time a button is pushed but for some reason, the image only moves once in a while when the button is pushed even though I know it received the button's IBAction because the NSLog in the IBAction displayed in the console, I have tried it two ways and both methods only worked sporadically

Method 1:

```
ranX = arc4random() %320;
ranY = arc4random() %480;
myImage.center = CGPointMake(ranX, ranY);
```

Method 2:

```
myImage.center = CGPointMake(arc4random() %320, arc4random() %480);
```

**One more thing: every time it does work, the next IBAction to run puts it right back into its original position.**

More information that might be pertinent I don't know, I do not have size classes enabled, it is triggered by touch up inside. I also DID make all the RNGs arc4random_uniform. 
**The problem is fixed, just deselect auto layout.**

Comment: not that its going to fix your problem, but you should use [arc4random_uniform()](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/arc4random_uniform.3.html) instead

Comment: what does it do? I know it has something to do with "modulo bias" but could you expand for my sake?

Comment: check out [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10984975/1219956)

Comment: Are you using auto layout?

Comment: Turning auto layout off fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

What control event did you add to your button? Since you stated it moves every once in a while, you might have done the wrong event. Try `UIControlEventTouchUpInside`
So,

```
[myButton addTarget:self action:@selector(moveImage) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

You're using a storyboard I see, Make sure that the send event for the button is "Touch Up Inside". Click on the button, go to the Connections Inspector and double check this.

Comment: I did select touch up inside as the mode when I created the button and it gave the option

Comment: Go to your Connections Inspector to see if it really was Touch Up Inside.

Comment: double checked, it is. Thanks though